# How to write a function that counts increases in a list?

Tags: recursion, racket

The task I'm given is, in Racket, to "write a function, countIncreases, which takes a list of numbers and returns how many times the consecutive numbers increase in value. For example, countIncreases '(1 3 2 4 5 1) should return 3 because there are three increases: 1 3, 2 4, 4 5."

I've written a recursive function with the base case being if the list is empty, return 0. I believe my problem is properly comparing one value to the next. Should I be using a standard library list iteration function like foldr or map to accomplish this?

My code and tests are below, and a screenshot of error messages is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOfTC.jpg)

```
(define (countIncreases aList)
  (if (empty? aList)
       0
       (if (< (first aList) (rest aList))
           (+ 1 (countIncreases (rest aList)))
           (countIncreases (rest aList)))))

(check-expect (countIncreases '(1 3 2 4 5 1)) 3)
(check-expect (countIncreases '()) 0)
(check-expect (countIncreases '(1 2 3 4 5)) 4)
(check-expect (countIncreases '(5 4 3 2 1 2)) 1)
```